# Change the size of an Imageview in android

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I set the default size of an imageview as `width=511` and `height=385` .
Source of the imageview is from drawable.
Based on a dynamic value I need to change the size of the image view or the image fit in to it.
For example I want to change the size of the imageview or image inside it to `width=140` and `height=100`

```
ImageView scale=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.scaleimage);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set the width and height attributes of your ImageView to specific values, the system will automatically scale you images to fit.

Unless I don't understand your question, I think it is as simple as:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scale_type="fitXY"
/>
```

To set this in code, try:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(140,100);
yourView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: This is done initially as width=511 and height=385 and I want to change this width and height programmatically

Comment: So you would do something like this: scaled.setWidth("140dp") programatically.

Comment: there is no method as setWidth for Imageview but it has setMaxWidth.
But it doesn't give the intended outcome it means no size change. :(

Comment: You are right, I added a different method to my original answer, which should work for you. I just found the answer by searching SO (so the answers are out there if you search).